# blog titles to come automatically

Tags: php

i want that in my blogs that i develop in PHP, the URL should look something like http://mysite.com/jan2006/best-day-of-my-life
instead of something like this http://mysite.com/viewblog.php?id=25
where "best day of my life" is the title of my blog post
what tool do i use to do this automatically ? 
and does this technique help search engine optimization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html) and Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). There is a mass of information out there on google & SO:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/htaccess.html

http://www.bloghash.com/2006/11/beginners-guide-to-htaccess-file-with-examples/

One thing to note, however, is that given the example you state you will still need a unique identifier to your specific blog post in your URL (namely the ID), e.g:

> something like http://mysite.com/jan2006/best-day-of-my-life instead
>   of something like this http://mysite.com/viewblog.php?id=25

It would actually need to be:

`http://mysite.com/25/jan2006/best-day-of-my-life`

or  `http://mysite.com/post/25/jan2006/best-day-of-my-life`

If you have an Apache hosting setup, in your root you would need a file named '.htaccess'. Its contents would look like (for example):

```
# set up mod rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ viewblog.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle requests for clean urls to blog posts
```

As for

> does this technique help search engine otimization ?

Yes, yes it does:

http://www.seocentro.com/articles/apache/mod_rewrite-seo-purposes.html

http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/create-seo-friendly-urls-using-mod-rewrite-and-php-part-1.html

http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls

http://webhostinggeeks.com/blog/2011/03/31/seo-friendly-links-with-mod_rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

From your admin dashboard look in your settings and there should be a section called permalinks. Here you can alter the way your permalinks are displayed.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags